# Output of SP to Excel

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I need to produce an Excel file using the output of approximately 25 SP's in SSIS. I am thinking of creating variables of `object` type and storing the output of execute SQL task in it. I can't figure out how to configure them to use as data source in the DFT? Any other suggestions in how to proceed about with this task would really be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've tried to clear your question up, but I still think it's not very clear, please relook at it.

Comment: The best method will depend on the contents of the SPs.  Are they UNION-able?  If not, that will complicate matters.  If they are, use the UNION ALL Data Transformation or, execute all of the SPs into a In Memory ADO recordset, then send that to excel.

Comment: Is this all one Excel sheet, or many worksheets in a single workbook?